# Delete Azure VM inside the backup items in Recovery Services Vault

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

Is there an automated way to delete the resources like Azure VM inside the backup items in Recovery Services Vault as there are thousands of VM inside of it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer through my research and I am now sharing it to you guys :-)

https://wmatthyssen.com/2020/11/17/azure-backup-remove-a-recovery-services-vault-and-all-cloud-backup-items-with-azure-powershell/

https://github.com/wimmatthyssen/Azure_Backup/blob/master/Remove_an_Azure_Backup_Recovery_Services_vault.ps1#L4